# How to neste pseudo-class and element in LESS?

Tags: html, css, less

I'm a newbie in LESS, I want to nested pseudo-class and element in LESS but I can't find any solution for my problem. This is my code:

```
.navbar-nav{
    li{
        &.active{
            a{
                color: #fe4444;
            }
        }

        a{
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 13px;

            &:hover{
                color: #fe4444;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to nested hover anchor tag in active class, hope anyone can help me out. Thank in advance.

Comment: do you mean while also maintaining the current hover effect too?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?  It has the hover effect show for hover or active state on the parent `li`.

```
.navbar-nav{
    li{
        &.active a, a:hover{
            color: #fe4444;
        }

        a{
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 13px;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to add a hover effect to an anchor in the `li` with an active class then I think you want to do this:

```
.navbar-nav
{
    li {
        &:active a:hover {
            color: #FE4444;
        }
    }
}
```